# Radeon ProRender ,auto Triangulate of models (Render)

Tags: rendering, topology

If I go and do a preview or even do a full render of Wireframe ,RPR will show models that are quads as fully Triangulated .Does anyone have any idea why ?
At first I though it would even do that if a model is full of Tris but it doesn't do that

[image]
[image]

Comment: All models are always triangulated at render time, viewport or otherwise. Triangles are the only thing a computer can draw, regardless of what the editing tools may make you believe. Are you experiencing any issues?

Comment: As far as I know or can see ,no issues .After looking at the info panel all I can see is Tris ,so makes sense ,Thanks.